# How to place view on top of another using constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to place CircleImageView on top of CardView. Something like this

[image]

This is what I have done

[image]

here's my xml code

```
   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
               android:layout_width="126dp"
               android:layout_height="126dp"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_image_2"
               app:civ_border_color="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
               app:civ_border_width="8dp"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView2"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cardView2"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cardView2"/>

           <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
               android:id="@+id/cardView2"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="900dp"
               app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

How do I place CircleImageView on Top of CardView and also place TextInputLayout below CircleImageView?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add  this line to your `CircleImageView`

```
 android:elevation="5dp"
```

Comment: How do I place TextInputLayout below CircleImageView in CardView

Comment: @Pennox Take it a rule: for a FrameLayout or ConstraintLayout, if you placed a view under another view (in the code), it will appear over him in the desgin.

Comment: @Pennox Also you can use the  android:elevation attribute to to determine which view appears at the top, the view that has android:elevation  equals 5 will be over the view that has elevation equals 2 and both will appear over the view that has elevation 0.. and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, on your `CircleImageView` set `android:elevation="8sp"` and to avoid any shadow use `android:outlineProvider="none"`